# Unity blurry sprite when changing camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, resolution, screen-resolution

I am struggling so much with resolution in Unity, I hope that someone could guide me how to resolve this.

I am making a game in Unity which implements a lot of zoom and dezoom, depending on where the player is.

My question is : "How it's possible to make an 2D sprite which will not blurry not regarding of the camera zoom"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunaty if you use pixel art there will always be a zoom level that creates blurry images. You can experiment with higher asset resolution and reduce compression but any form of pixel art has its limitations when you want to zoom.

However you can try the svg-importer of unity and use vector based art. Last time I checked the svg-importer worked ok-ish. You need to include it to your project in the package manager. Oh and it's called

[vector Graphics](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.vectorgraphics@2.0/manual/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

There is a good way to fix this. You can change the settings on the sprite from Bilinear to Point(No Filter). This will make your sprite much better.

Comment: Oh I have not thought about that. But you are still left with the pixels right?

Comment: If you are using pixel art, yes, but if not, no.

Comment: And do you mind up voting my answer? It would really help me.